# MongoDB backup and restore in production

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb, amazon-ec2, production

I have a MERN app running on AWS EC2.I guess terminating the instance will remove all databases. So is there any good practice in backing up my MongoDB collections locally or saving them in remote?. I want to have a backup of my production db. Is there any suggestion how can I regularly backup and save my Database?

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 1):

You can get mongoDB database backup and restore script in PHP from here
https://github.com/sulochanatutorials/php-mongodb-backup-restore

Comment: Love the code that you have put simple and clean, however, I would not recommend using it for restoring in Production, for backup can be used. Faced some issue while restoring.